# Showing that $M_n(\mathcal{A})$ is a *-Algebra

Tags: operator-algebras

Having a $C^*$ Algebra $\mathcal{A}$ I want to show that $M_n(\mathcal{A})$ is a $*-$Algebra with product and involution:

$$(a_{i,j})\cdot(b_{i,j}) = \sum_{k=1}^n a_{i,k}b_{k,j} $$
$$ (a_{i,j})^* = (a_{j,i}^*)$$

then if I consider the norm,

$$\|(a_{i,j}) \cdot (b_{i,j})\| = max_{i} \sum_{j=1}^n \left \|\sum_{k=1}^na_{i,k}b_{k,j}\right \| \le max_{i} \sum_{j=1}^n \sum_{k=1}^n \|a_{i,k}\| \|b_{k,j}\| \dots ?$$

but I should get $\|(a_{i,j}) \cdot (b_{i,j})\| \le \|(a_{i,j})\| \cdot \|(b_{i,j})\|$

Also how to deal with involution? Thanks

Comment: How do you define the norm in $M_n(A) $?

Comment: I guess it's just the operator norm in finite dimension, so something like $\| B \| = sup_{\|x\| \le 1} \|Bx\|$ where $B$ is in $M_n(\mathcal{A})$ but I don't know how to use it in this context..